# S3 replication: Access denied: Amazon S3 can't detect whether versioning is enabled on the destination bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, bucket

I'm configuring a replication between two s3 buckets. but I get the error

> Access denied: Amazon S3 can't detect whether versioning is enabled on
>   the destination bucket.

The destination bucket is in another account, different region.
Here is the bucket policy in the destination bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::destination",
                "arn:aws:s3:::destination/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:userId": [
                        "AROAS3AHCETXXDF5Z5GVG:*",
                        "AROAS3AHCETXX2DMH4JPY:*",
                        "AROAS3AHCEXXX4SNCNTNV:*",
                        "AROAVJZZXXXXXZBBR7PN6L:*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "S3ReplicationPolicyStmt1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:PutBucketVersioning",
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::destination",
                "arn:aws:s3:::destination/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My buckets are highly confidential, so I first deny all access except for some roles: So in the condition, I have the replication role ID excluded too.

Why the replication role is still not allowed to replicate? What is wrong with this bucket policy ?
In the above policy I actually authorize the replication role twice. in both statements.

Here is the replication IAM role policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::source",
                "arn:aws:s3:::source/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:ReplicateDelete",
                "s3:ReplicateTags",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::destination/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried deleting the explicite deny statement and test the replication, the source bucket gets the Versioning and **I had no access denied, but objects are not replicated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to white list the replication role in the source bucket as well. Both buckets have similar policy so It was necessary to allow the replication role to access the source.

Answer (score 0):

For my experience, AWS S3 policies follow a white-list approach, meaning that you first need to add statements for the actions you want to allow, and then a final statement to deny everything else.

So in your case, try to just switch the statements.

Comment: in my policy I actually authorize the replication role twice. in both statements.

Comment: @Souad wait, just re-read your question. You said that's the policy in the destination bucket, but what's the policy of the user / role you are using in the origin? You need to grant that user / role permission (in IAM) to use GetBucketVersioning

Comment: please check the iam role in my question update. I do have GetBucketVersioning  allowed in the role.

Comment: @Souad notice that in your IAM policy, the resource is `"arn:aws:s3:::destination/*"`, however, `s3:GetBucketVersioning` works at the bucket level, not at the object level. That is, the resource must be `"arn:aws:s3:::destination"`. However, the `Replicate*` works at the object level, so you will need to have different statements. Have a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazons3.html#amazons3-bucket for which resource type do you need to use for each action.